# Bugzilla Internal Server Error 500 - .htaccess in Bugzilla Directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, bugzilla

i have an error after the installation of bugzilla.

The browser shows a server error 500. The Error.log of Apache show the lines below:

```
**[Fri Nov 27 15:48:22.264120 2015] [core:alert] [pid 2116:tid 1008] [client ::1:50338] C:/bugzilla/.htaccess: Invalid command 'deny', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration**
```

The Configuration of **.htaccess**:

```
Don't allow people to retrieve non-cgi executable files or our private data
<FilesMatch (\.pm|\.pl|\.tmpl|localconfig.*)$>
  <IfModule mod_version.c>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
         deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      <IfModule mod_perl.c>
          deny from all
      </IfModule>
      <IfModule !mod_perl.c>
          deny from all
      </IfModule>
    </IfVersion>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_version.c>
     deny from all
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

The option "Required all granted" is also not allowed.

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't figure out why the 2.4 syntax doesn't work either, you could load mod_access_compat which provides allow/deny/order directives.

Comment: Thank you, im load the modul mod_access_compat and bugzilla running.